# When I search with child is null in Firebase android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code:

```
String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
myRef = database.getReference("reserva/");
myRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      String value = dataSnapshot.child("reserva/1/status").getValue(String.class);
        String status;
        TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
        if (value != null) {
            status = dataSnapshot.getKey() + getString(R.string.statusreservafeita);
            textview2.setText(status + value);
        } else
            textview2.setText(R.string.statusreservafail );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
        textview2.setText(R.string.statusreservafail );
    }
});
```

My data :

```
 "reserva" : {
  "1" : {
    "email" : "teste@teste.com",
    "status" : "check in"
  },
  "2" : {
    "email" : "fabio@ciaf.com.br",
    "status" : "check out"
  },
  "123" : {
    "email" : "fbaoo07@gmail.com",
    "status" : "reservado"
  }
}
```

When I put an email teste@teste.com it returns null. I need it to return the status, but it returns null. I think I am missing a child.

Comment: What a strange title.

Comment: Strange question too

Comment: Please put proper English in your question.

Comment: What line is the error? We aren't magicians.

Comment: It seems that @Frank van Puffelen is a true magician in this case.. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code, but nothing major.

Here's the snippet that will most likely work:

```
myRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String status = childSnapshot.child("status").getValue(String.class);
        }
    }
```

The changes I made are:

1. I added a loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`. A query can return multiple children. For that reason it returns a list, even when there is only one match. By looping over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` we get each match.
2. I get the value directly from the `statusSnapshot` instead of looking it up from the root.

Alternative, if you want to look up the child by its absolute path, you can do something like this:

```
statusRef = database.getReference("reserva/1/status");
statusRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String status = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    }
    ...
```